# Create sequence based on grouping variable in R

Tags: r, sequence

I'm looking for a way to create a sequence of numbers ($C) that ascend every time a string changes in($A). This is contingent on a grouping variable ($B).
Example:

```
A    B C
a1   1 1
a1   1 1
a1   1 1
a10  1 2
a10  1 2
a2   1 3
a1   2 1
a20  2 2
a30  2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or with `dplyr`

```
df %>% group_by(B) %>% mutate(C = match(A, unique(A)))
# Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
# Groups: B
# 
#     A B C
# 1  a1 1 1
# 2  a1 1 1
# 3  a1 1 1
# 4 a10 1 2
# 5 a10 1 2
# 6  a2 1 3
# 7  a1 2 1
# 8 a20 2 2
# 9 a30 2 3
```

With `base R`

```
df$C <- with(df, ave(as.character(A), B, FUN=function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

Comment: This'll not work for example if `df$A[6]` can be `"a1"`.

Comment: It appears that the column has been grouped. If not, that step would have to become the first in this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`, could use the new `rleid` function

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5
setDT(df)[, C := rleid(A), by = B]
#      A B C
# 1:  a1 1 1
# 2:  a1 1 1
# 3:  a1 1 1
# 4: a10 1 2
# 5: a10 1 2
# 6:  a2 1 3
# 7:  a1 2 1
# 8: a20 2 2
# 9: a30 2 3
```