# Consecutive Across and Unique Number Within Group

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a data frame, which looks like this:

```
DF_A <- data.frame(
  Group_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
  Group_2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A")
)
```

I would like to assign a **consecutive number for Group_1** IDs which should be **unique for the case of identical Group_2** IDs. For example, A+A starts with 1, A+B proceeds with 2 (same Group_1 ID, but new Group_2 ID), ..., A+A is again 1 (obviously a repetition). B+A is 1 (new Group_1 ID), ..., B+A (same Group_1 ID, but new Group_2 ID)...and so forth.

The result should look like this.

```
DF_B <- data.frame(
  Group_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
  Group_2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A"),
  ID      = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

I investigated various posts on corresponding approaches such as single [groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411973/create-sequence-based-on-grouping-variable-in-r) [within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859175/how-to-rank-within-groups-in-r), or a [combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame) - without any success - this case is not covered by previous posts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean create `factor` out of combinations of Group1 and Group2? row 9 should have ID=3?

Comment: A number, yes. The result is not a factor. One might consider to 'create' a factor value as intermediate step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with `ave` is

```
DF_A$ID <- ave(DF_A$Group_2, DF_A$Group_1, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x)))

DF_A
#   Group_1 Group_2 ID
#1        A       A  1
#2        A       B  2
#3        A       C  3
#4        A       A  1
#5        A       B  2
#6        B       A  1
#7        B       B  2
#8        B       A  1
#9        B       C  3
#10       C       A  1
```

---

The equivalent `dplyr` way is :

```
library(dplyr)
DF_A %>%
  group_by(Group_1) %>%
  mutate(ID = match(Group_2, unique(Group_2)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer work best for me. However, all other answers might be valuable for further applications. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can split into groups by Group_1, then create factor out of your combinations within each group then convert into integer

```
DF_A$ID <- unlist(by(DF_A, DF_A$Group_1, function(x) as.integer(factor(x$Group_2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `dense_rank` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

DF_A2 <- DF_A %>%
  group_by(Group_1) %>%
  mutate(ID = dense_rank(Group_2)) %>%
  ungroup()
DF_A2
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    Group_1 Group_2    ID
#    <fct>   <fct>   <int>
#  1 A       A           1
#  2 A       B           2
#  3 A       C           3
#  4 A       A           1
#  5 A       B           2
#  6 B       A           1
#  7 B       B           2
#  8 B       A           1
#  9 B       C           3
# 10 C       A           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the integer values of the factor levels.  We can simply wrap `Group_2` in `c()` to drop the factor attribute.

```
within(DF_A, { ID = ave(c(Group_2), Group_1, FUN = c) })
#   Group_1 Group_2 ID
# 1        A       A  1
# 2        A       B  2
# 3        A       C  3
# 4        A       A  1
# 5        A       B  2
# 6        B       A  1
# 7        B       B  2
# 8        B       A  1
# 9        B       C  3
# 10       C       A  1
```

Comment: even shorter with `within`? `within(DF_A, ID <- ave(c(Group_2), Group_1, FUN = c))`

Comment: @chinsoon12 - most definitely!